# Convert 1 to 32 bit unsigned in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, binary, decimal, 32-bit

We need to pass BLE command to one device where we need to pass offset in 6 to 10 where each block of 32 bytes. Any one has idea how can we pass that ? Please suggest.

Attached is the request format image. [image: Link]

I have created below two methods for the command.

A> let value: [UInt8] = [0x05,0x05,0x00,0xA0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x10 ];

B>

[image: Attached is the image.]

Comment: For me that sounds like you want to do some bit shift operations. I guess at least some code will be needed to show how you achieve the communication with the BLE device.

Comment: Edited question.

Comment: @DavidMichaelHuber - Did you get the chance to review. Please help.

Comment: @holex - Did you get the chance to review. Please help.

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Post actual code, as text, in your question. Images can't be searched or referenced and they are harder to read.

Comment: I agree with @rmaddy. Also it is still not clear where the exact problem is. Is there something like a log, a compile error or anything like that?